# How to read array line in sequence from Input

Tags: arrays, perl

I have some trouble
with array, how to read an array line in sequence from Input.
Here's my code.

**sites.txt**: (input file)

```
site1
site2
site3
```

**program**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


my $file = 'sites.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)
     or die "Couldn't open file !'$file' $!";

my @rows = <$fh>;
chomp @rows;
foreach my $site (@rows) {
    $sitename    = $site;
    @domains     = qw(.com .net .org);
    foreach $dns (@domains){
        $domain = $dns;
        print "$site$dns\n";
    }
}
```

and the output is like this

```
site1.com
site1.net
site1.org
site2.com
site2.net
site2.org
site3.com
site3.net
site3.org
```

I understand until that point,but i want make it the first element of array from @domains
reading until the end of Input line first,
then looping back to the 1st line of Input and going to the next element of array so 
the output would be like this,

```
site1.com
site2.com
site3.com
site1.net
site2.net
site3.net
site1.org
site2.org
site3.org
```

it possible doing it? or need another module.sorry for basic question 
I'll be really appreciated for the Answers.
thanks :)

Comment: Sorry my bad,i dont know.i don't see any perl option there :)

Comment: Just reverse the order of the two loops to get the desired output

Comment: Can u write the sample code,im new in perl...thanks

Comment: @andrew99 I just posted an answer. Should I further elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand the answer sir,yeah it would be nice if u can elaborate it further,coz im new

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over all your sites and then (for each site) add the domain to the current site.

In pseudocode this is:

```
foreach site
    foreach domain
       print site + domain
```

Swap your loops so that the logic is

```
foreach domain
    foreach site
        print site + domain
```

Note that this is pseudocode, not Perl.

---

In "real" Perl this would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'sites.txt';
open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file )
  or die "Couldn't open file !'$file' $!";

my @rows = <$fh>;
chomp @rows;

my @domains = qw(.com .net .org);

foreach my $dns (@domains) {
    foreach my $site (@rows) {
        print "$site$dns\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
site1.com
site2.com
site3.com
site1.net
site2.net
site3.net
site1.org
site2.org
site3.org
```

Please **always** include `use strict;` and `use warnings;` on top of your scripts. These two statements will show you the most common errors in your code.

Comment: Thanks,it work now.can u explain me the error part.cause i don't understand the different with my script.

Comment: You're welcome. I almost got desperate. Consider this: You need 3 items from 3 shops. **Your code says** "Go to shop_1 and buy item_1, then go to shop_2 and buy item_1, then go to shop_3 and buy item_1. After that, do the same for shop_2 and shop_3." **My code says** "Go to shop_1 and buy items_1, _2, _3. Then go to shop_2 and _3 and do the same.". The result is the same, it's just a different order.

Comment: yeay,thanks!very clear explanation!i really got it now.thanks for the humble and patient!